# Eigenvector basis of a linear operator with repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be the matrix representation of a linear operator $T: V \to V$. Assume, for the sake of simplicity, $A$ is $3\times 3$. And suppose $A$ has two repeated eigenvalues $\lambda_r$ and one distinct eigenvalue $\lambda_d$. It follows a single eigenvector is associated to $\lambda_r$ (or two equal eigenvectors, which is the same). Then the eigenvectors $\beta, \alpha$ can never span $V$, since it is assumed that $V$ is three-dimensional.

In short, it does not seem possible that repeated eigenvalues are associated to eigenvectors such that the set of those vectors is a basis of the space in question.

However, in Hoffman's classic book, *Linear algebra*, we read:

> $T$ is diagonalizable if there is a basis for $V$ each vector of which is a characteristic vector of $T$. (...) We certainly do not require the scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ be distinct; indeed, they may all be the same scalar.

Here, $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $[T]_B$ under the basis $B$ consisting of the eigenvectors of $T$. In other words, $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are the eigenvalues of $T$.

So this statement contradicts my initial reasoning. In fact, it claims one *can* have repeated eigenvalues *and* a basis of $V$ consisting of the eigenvectors associated to those eigenvalues. How is this possible?

---

For those concerned with the specific context of this doubt, I was observing the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        -9 & 4 & 4 \\ 
        -8 & 3 & 4 \\ 
        -16 & 8 & 7
    \end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix has

\begin{align*}
    \det(A - \lambda I ) &= (-1-\lambda)^2(3 - \lambda)
.\end{align*}

From this follows $\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = 3$ are eigenvalues of $A$. By
solving the homogeneous systems $A + I = 0, A - 3I = 0$ we find the eigenspaces

\begin{align*}
    \Lambda_1 &= \text{span}\Big\{\Big(\frac{1}{2}, 1, 0\Big), \Big(\frac{1}{2},
        0, 1\Big)\Big\} \\ 
    \Lambda_2 &= \text{span}\Big\{\Big( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 1\Big)\Big\}
.\end{align*}

The eigenvectors are then $\alpha = (1/2, 1/2, 1), \beta = (1, 1, 1)$. They can not span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and this seems a direct consequence of the fact that an eigenvalue is repeated (namely, $-1$).

Comment: It is certainly possible to have repeated eigenvalues and a basis of eigenvectors. Consider the identity matrix.

Comment: In your example, the eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $-1$ can be taken to be $(1,2,0)$ and $(1,0,2)$. Together with the eigenvector $(1,1,2)$ for the other eigenvalue, they span ${\bf R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We even have names for this. The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the number of times it is an eigenvalue, the geometric multiplicity is the number of associated eigenvectors.   The geometric is bound between 1 and the algebraic multiplicity (You always have at least 1, at most the number of times it is an eigenvalue)..   A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if every geometric multiplicty is equal to the algebraic multiplicity.

For example,  $Ix=x$  for every vector $x$, so every non-zero vector is an eigenvector for the identity matrix with eigenvalue 1.   So any spanning set will be a basis of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Working in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ you can start with any three linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and any scalars $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3,$ and find a matrix $M$ having eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs $(\lambda_i, v_i).$ You can do this by reversing the process of diagonalisation: stick the $\lambda_i$ into a diagonal matrix $D$ and let $P$ be the matrix whose columns are the $v_i$. Letting $M := PDP^{-1},$ we have that $$M v_i = PD e_i = P \lambda_i e_i = \lambda_i v_i,$$ where, $e_i$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ standard basis vector.

This explains the passage of Hoffman's book, the $\lambda_i$ can be anything you want. We could take them all to be $0,$ for instance.

**Example.**

Taking $\lambda_i := 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 3,$ we get that $D = 0,$ so $M = 0.$ The zero matrix is then an example of a matrix with repeated eigenvalues admitting a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

**Example.**

Letting $v_i := e_i$ for all $i,$ we have that $M = D.$ So any diagonal matrix admits a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of dimensions of eigenspaces i.e. $2+1$ equals the dimension of $\mathbb R^3$  so it is spanned by the eigenspaces. Further, $(1,1,1)$ is in the $W=span\{(1/2,1,0),(1/2,0,1)\}$ so $span\{(1,1,1)\}\subset W$ eventually.